# Company Location no longer being sent in OAuth Response?

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I have an app that uses the OAuth protocol to sign in users with LinkedIn.

Yesterday I noticed that `location` information is being sent for each company in the user's history. Below is an example response I captured from my own LinkedIn profile -

```
"positions" => {
  "_total" => 5,
  "values" => [
    {
      "company" => {
        "id" => 2642941,
        "industry" => "Internet",
        "name" => "Shinra Corp",
        "size" => "1-10 employees",
        "type" => "Privately Held"
      },
      "id" => 40802043,
      "isCurrent" => true,
      "location" => {
        "country" => {
          "code" => "us", 
          "name" => "United States"
        }, 
        "name" => "Atlanta Area"
      },
      "startDate" => {
        "month" => 6, 
        "year" => 2015
      },
      "title" => "Developer"
    },
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

Note the `"location" =>` information now present.

However I tried it again today, and there is no `"location"` information. Nothing else has changed on my end, and my LinkedIn profile has not been touched in any way. Also confirmed this behavior with 2 other accounts.

Did this information recently disappear? Is there a way to still access it?

Is this change documented anywhere? I imagine several features rely on it, so I'm very surprised to see it disappear without warning.